# Core data - Fetching results by combining the data of two tables

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have three tables: Assignments, Questions, Assignment-Questions

Assignment table will have informations related to Assignment like its id, title etc.

Questions table will hold assignment questions and has properties like question ID, question title, question text etc.

Questions table does not have assignment ID as a property because to avoid duplicate entries in Questions table as more than one Assignments can share same question.

Assignment and Questions are related through a table named Assignment-Questions which has assignment ID and question ID.

For Example: Lets say Assignment 1 has 3 questions with ID 1, 2 and 3

At this instance, both Questions and Assignment-Questions table will have 3 entries

Next, Assignment 2 has 3 questions with ID 4, 5 and 1(same as assignment 1)

At this instance, Questions table will have 5 entries(1 question is common in both Assignment 1 and 2) and Assignment-Questions will have 6 entries.(3 each for assignment 1 and 2)

With this scenario, I want to create a fetch controller to fetch all the questions related to assignment 2 in the order it is added to Assignment-Questions table.

I am not pretty sure how to write a predicate and sort descriptor where the result is combination of two tables by maintaining the oder. I tried few permutation and combination and nothing seems to be working for me. Please help me with suggestions.

Comment: Rather than doing that, maybe you could create and save an array of the questions when they are added to the table, then retrieve that array instead.

Comment: I can give you a predicate, but not a sort descriptor for that. - Fetching and sorting *AssignmentQuestion* objects is easier. Could that be an alternative?

Comment: Martin, My view controller is completely implemented based on fetch controller. As per my knowledge goes we can't create a fetch controller without a sort descriptor. Any thoughts?

Comment: A FRC needs a sort descriptor, that is correct. I don't know how to make a sort descriptor for the *Question* entity according to your needs. My only idea is to fetch and sort *AssignmentQuestion* instead. From each *AssignmentQuestion* you have a pointer to the corresponding *Question*, so you can use the *AssignmentQuestion* objects to display the question title, text etc.

Answer (score 0):

@MartinR has it right. You operate on the join table. I've guessed at some field names and such, and the code is untested of course, but it should get you going:

```
fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AssignmentQuestion"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"question.order" ascending:YES]];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"assignment = %@", assignment];
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"question"];
```

Then in your VC you can operate on the FRC of AssignmentQuestion objects:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Question* question = [[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] question];
    ...
}
```